# SAS do loop with array

Tags: arrays, sas

I first store the character elements of array with size 3.

```
data _null_;

    array fruit[3] $10 ("apple" "orange" "lemon");

    call symput("fruit1", fruit1);
    call symput("fruit2", fruit2);
    call symput("fruit3", fruit3);

run;
```

I would like to print all element of the array `fruit`,

```
%put &fruit1;
%put &fruit2;
%put &fruit3;
```

Is it possible to do using do-loop?

Comment: I think you are missing something fundamental about the SAS language here.  The array statement there is nearly pointless: it's a slightly quicker way to initialize those three variables, but an even quicker way would be to set them with %let statements directly. The array itself disappears after the `run;` ends the data step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the SQL method to create variables. Here's two ways to display the macro variables, one using a data step and one using a macro do loop:

```
*Generate sample data;
data have;
    input fruit $20.;
    cards;
    apple
    banana
    grapes
    ;
run;

*Create macro variables;
proc sql noprint;
    select fruit 
    into :fruit1-:fruit1000
    from have;
quit;

*Store number of macro variables;
%let nobs=&sqlobs.;

%put &nobs;

*Display macro variables in data step;
data _null_;
    do i=1 to &nobs.;
        have=symget(catt("fruit", i));
        put have;
    end;
run;

*Display macro variables using macro logic;
%macro display_vars;
    %do i=1 %to &nobs.;
        %put &&fruit&i.;
    %end;
%mend;
%display_vars;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data _null_;

  array fruit[3] $10 ("apple" "orange" "lemon");
  length all_fruit $100;

  do i =1 to dim(fruit);
    all_fruit = compress(all_fruit||'|'||fruit[i]);
    put fruit[i];
  end;

  call symputx("allfruit",all_fruit);

 run;

%put &allfruit
```